# Where does an object with density lower than outer space go?

Tags: density, buoyancy, thought-experiment

Assume there was an object with lower density than that of the interstellar medium (which is extremely low already at just a few particles per cubic meter).

If that object were released on Earth, where would it end up? Am I correct in assuming that it would travel all the way to either the L1 or L2 Lagrange point?

Comment: Are you assuming that L1 and L2 have the lowest densities? I don't think that's true, but the main force on such an object would come from the pressure of the solar wind and one can assume that it would get blown out of the solar system.

Comment: Low density items float/rise because the gravitational force on them is less than the gravitational force on the surrounding medium, forcing the surrounding medium to flow around and below the item. At some point, the surrounding medium will become too thin to have any effect, and gravity would take over. So I'm guessing that, even though it's of lower density, it would float right around where space thins out to nearly the interstellar medium.